# Sum array values until a specific value is reached and return the used values

Tags: javascript, arrays, subset, subset-sum

Is there a function that can take a array of numbers and a specific number add some of the numbers in the array to get the specific number and return in a array the numbers it used that you gave?

an example of this would be:

```
var specificFunction = function(list, target){
    // some kind of code here that adds the numbers in the array till it gets the number you want and returns in a array the numbers it used to get the number you want
};
specificFunction([256,8,512,8192,32,1024,16,2], 9224); // [8192,1024,8]
```

If there is not such a function then how would I go about making one?

If there is such a function then where can I find it or is it built in?

Comment: Google for Subset sum problem.

Comment: this is the first time i have seen this after hours of searching and answers my question but i have yet to see a javascript implementation if you can provide a link to an example of its implementation in javascript i would greatly appreciate it @thefourtheye

Comment: I got this from googling. https://gist.github.com/lrvick/1381084

Comment: thank you @thefourtheye if you want to put this as the answer i will accept it as you have answered my question fully

Comment: Thats okay :-) Try to implement the algorithm yourself, it will be fun.

Comment: thank you and i will this was what i was looking for all day yesterday and i am glad you were able to help me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61781/discussion-between-kamijou-touma-and-thefourtheye). @thefourtheye